# What jquery tooltip plugin should I use?

Tags: jquery

I've heard of Qtip, and it looks good for what I want to use.  Is this the most common one?  Are there any other jquery tooltip plugins that people recommend?  I want to pop up a bubble with images and formatted text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) is excellent. If you have no reason *not* to use it, I'd suggest implementing it immediately and get back to work ;) That being said, you be interested in [**15 jQuery Plugins to Create User-Friendly Tooltips**](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-an-user-friendly-tooltip/).

Comment: It does not support jquery 1.4. What a pity.

Answer (score 1):

I used qtip and was pretty impressed until it started interfering an infragistics grid control.  I'm now also looking for a very simple tooltip plugin that doesn't cause the problems that Qtip caused.

For anyone curious in the infragistics details, it was causing the dropdownlist items as defined in a valuelist to not show.

Answer (score 0):

check the nice ones with demo here http://miniajax.com/

Answer (score 0):

This works for you.

http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/